# R Scorecard Package Id Column

Tags: r

IN R I am using SCORECARD PACKAGE.
Everything is fine but,

the final tables does not show my ID column!

```
score_list = lapply(dt_list, function(x) scorecard_ply(x,card, only_total_score=FALSE))
```

for ex: my table's ID is PERSON_ID,
R gives me a final list (score_list)

But it just gives the scores like :

```
rows     1    2   3   4   5
scores 942  898 919 546 662
```

off course I need PERSON_ID & Scores. (I  dont know which score belongs to which PERSON_ID! ridicolus!)

SO it is unable to be used... because I need PERSON_ID & SCORES.

Can anyone help me ?
Thanks

Comment: You should make a reproducible example because its hard for us to see what your problem is without your data.

Comment: the problme is not about my data, the thing I want to ask is, how do we describe our ID column in scorecard package code? what am I missing?

Comment: If you make a reproducible example (using either your data or some synthetic data, or the example data from the package) then we can give you a **reproducible answer** that you can simply run. Otherwise we are guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(scorecard)

# load germancredit data
data("germancredit")
germancredit$PERSON_ID = row.names(germancredit) 

# filter variable via missing rate, iv, identical value rate
dt_sel = var_filter(germancredit, "creditability", var_rm = 'PERSON_ID')

# woe binning ------
bins = woebin(dt_sel, y = "creditability")

# scorecard
card = scorecard2(bins, dt_sel, y = 'creditability')
score1 = scorecard_ply(germancredit, card, var_kp = 'PERSON_ID')
```